# Converting a string of coordinate pairs to an array object of coordinate pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string of coordinate pairs in the format "[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]" and I want to convert it to a genuine array object so that I have [ [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] ]. In javascript how do I convert the string to a proper array of arrays to get the above representation. Once I have converted do I need to add the outer sqaure brackets or is that by implication after the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

```
var coordinateArray = JSON.parse('[' + yourCoordinateString + ']');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can borrow `JSON.parse`...

```
var arr = JSON.parse( '[' + my_string + ']' );
```

or `eval()` if you know the content is secure...

```
var arr = eval( '[' + my_string + ']' );
```

... or the `Function` constructor...

```
var arr = (new Function( 'return [' + my_string + '];' ))();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse('['+[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]"+']');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function coordinateStringToArray(coordinateString) {
            //Remove the first and last brackets, then split it by the delimeter.
            var sets = coordinateString.substr(1, coordinateString.length - 2).split('],[');
            var arr = new Array();

            for (i = 0; i < sets.length; ++i) {
                var set = sets[i];
                arr.push(new Array(set.substr(0,1), set.substr(2,1)));
            }

            return arr;
        }
```